# How do I print one letter of a string that was input by the user in Java?

Tags: java, string, java.util.scanner

I have read the other similar questions but they weren't much help. 
I want to prompt the user to input a three word string and I then want to output the capital of the first character of each word.

For example..

the user inputs `"Benjamin Andrew Linus"`

and the program prints out `"BAL"`.

I tried using `char name = charAt()` but that's not what I should use for this.

This is what I have so far...

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Initials {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

     Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter your full name: ");
        String first_name = in.next();
        String middle_name = in.next();
        String last_name = in.next();
     }
}
```

Comment: use ```in.nextLine();```

Comment: wouldn't that use all three words to create the string though?

Comment: Sorry, I totally overlooked something. Check out my updated code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing the entire code wouldn't help much. I just give you a hint.

This could be helpful:

```
Character.isUpperCase(first_name.charAt(<int poistion in string>));
```

Comment: Ok, that seemed to work, but how do I then call on it to print it out?

Comment: If `Character.isUpperCase` return `true`, then you will print with the exact same  int position in `first_name.charAt(<int poistion in string>)`. If the uppercase character is always at the beginning of each word, then it should be `charAt(0)`. If the uppercase appears at any place of the string then you have to iterate through each character of the string to find the uppercase.

Comment: Right, but i tried String initial = first_name.charAt(0) and it says you cant change from a string to character

Comment: `String initial = String.valueOf(first_name.charAt(0)); ` should fix this issue. Your biggest help is JAVA API.

Comment: Got it! Thanks so much man. what does the "valueOf" command do?

Answer (score 0):

Try using split to split the full name into three strings.

So you can try the following:

```
String name = in.nextLine().split(" ");
String initial = "";
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    initials += name[0].charAt(0);
}
```

Comment: I tried the first one but i got the same error that I got when i tried using charAt() like you did.
"cannot convert from int to string" 
Should i try casking it?

Comment: Int? It should be a string though. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next()

Answer (score 0):

Using the answers given to me, this is what finally worked for me...

```
System.out.print("Enter your full name: ");
    String first_name = in.next();
    String middle_name = in.next();
    String last_name = in.next();

    String initial1 = String.valueOf(first_name.charAt(0)).toUpperCase();
    String initial2 = String.valueOf(middle_name.charAt(0)).toUpperCase();
    String initial3 = String.valueOf(last_name.charAt(0)).toUpperCase();

    System.out.print(initial1 + initial2 + initial3);
```